# I just moved the close/minimize/maxmize buttons to the right, how can I undo the action?

Tags: 13.04, gnome

I used this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

How can I reset them back to the right?

Comment: @JohnWHSmith notice that the user is not asking about moving the buttons to the right but how to undone it/move them to the left.

Comment: @xangua : both imply the modification of the same GNOME parameter, with opposite value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
```